# How to get uri from routs using route name in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In `routes/web.php` I have route

```
Route::get('/answers', [StaticPagesController::class, 'answers'])->name('answers.index');
```

In my application I using route name to generate url

```
route('answers.index') // result is http://example.com/answers
```

But how can I get only uri (`/answers`), using route name?

To add `.active` class to nav items (bootstrap 4) I use next construction

```
{{request()->is('/answers') ? 'active' : ''}}
```

But in this case, the whole meaning of named routes is lost. If I change the uri, then I have to change it in all places where I use this approach.

How can I get uri using route name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the current route is named something:

```
Route::currentRouteNamed('answers.index')

request()->route()->named('answers.index')
```

These take patterns so you could do other checks if needed:

```
...->named('answers.*')
```